# Scrapy, can't crawl any page: "TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out."

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

New to programming

Can't scrape content from some domain belonging to the same website.

For example, I can scrape `it.example.com`, `es.example.com`, `pt.example.com` but when I try to do the same with `fr.example.com` or `us.example.com`, I get:

```
2017-12-17 14:20:27 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console 
listening on 127.0.0.1:6025
2017-12-17 14:21:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages 
(at 
0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-12-17 14:22:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages 
(at 
0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-12-17 14:22:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: 
Retrying 
<GET https://fr.example.com/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): TCP 
connection 
timed out: 110: Connection timed out.
```

Here's the Spider *some.py*

```
import scrapy
import itertools

class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'some'
   allowed_domains = ['https://fr.example.com']
   def start_requests(self):
    categories = [ 'thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3',]
           base = "https://fr.example.com/things?t={category}&p={index}"

    for category, index in itertools.product(categories, range(1, 11)):
        yield scrapy.Request(base.format(category=category, index=index))

def parse(self, response):
    response.selector.remove_namespaces()
    info1 = response.css("span.info1").extract()
    info2 = response.css("span.info2").extract()

    for item in zip(info1, info2):
        scraped_info = {
            'info1': item[0],
            'info2': item[1]
            }

        yield scraped_info
```

**What I have tried:**

1. Run the spider from a different IP (same problem with the same domains)
2. Add a pool of IPs (didn't work)
3. Found somewhere on Stackoverflow: in `setting.py`, set

   `USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) 
   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 
   Safari/537.36'`
4. `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: did you check this url in browser today? maybe server has problem today and it doesn't work.

Comment: First check in browser and then see scrapy. Some sites require specific country IPs

Comment: The site is online and I can access it from my current location without any problem

Comment: you run it using pool of IP's - what IP's ? Proxy servers IP's ? They may not work sometimes. Did you check url in browser using those IP's ?

Comment: For whatever reason, the same  '(base = "https://fr.example.com/things?t={category}&p={index}")' that worked for other domains, didn't for FR and US. I just added www. to fr.example.com and it worked. Having '(base = "https://www.fr.example.com/things?t={category}&p={index}")' works. No idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Try to access the page with the `requests` package instead of `scrapy`, and see if it works.

```
import requests

url = 'fr.example.com'

response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. What do I have to change in my script to make it scrape the info I need?

Comment: EDIT: For whatever reason, the same _base = "https://fr.example.com/things?t={category}&p={index}"_ that worked for other domains, didn't for FR and US. I just added www. to fr.example.com and it worked. Having _base = "https://www.fr.example.com/things?t={category}&p={index}"_  works. No idea why.

Comment: @Rawhide glad my answer was useful still.